# Python HTTP Server gets multiple requests from iPhone

Tags: iphone, python, http, request

I created a very basic Python http server (Python v3.2) that uses BaseHTTPRequestHandler to handle GET requests.  It works fine when I use any web browser on a computer.  But, when I use a mobile browser on an iPhone, I always see three GET requests.

For example, if I run this:

```
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler (BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)

print('running server on port 80')
server = HTTPServer(('', 80), MyHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

..and then I go to my web browser on my iPhone and enter "192.168.1.191/blah", the output looks like this:

```
/blah
/blah
/blah
```

but if I do it from a computer, it only sends one GET request, so the output is this:

```
/blah
```

Can anyone explain to me why it behaves this way with the iPhone?  It consistently sends 3 requests every single time.  Is there any way around this?

By the way, if I use an Apache server, the iPhone does not behave this way.  It only sends one GET request.  It's only when I'm using Python to run a server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Safari returns a request up to three times - obviously in case of *some* HTTP error.
Generating a proper HTTP response from inside your do_GET() method will solve this issue.

Comment: Ok, so would I just add the following line to my do_GET() method?    self.send_response(200)  When I do that it just seems to lock up for a second, but yeah, it only sends one GET.

Comment: Sorry, working as it should with one request arriving on the server side by Safari.

Comment: I am using AJAX to send different GETs to my Python server, back to back.  When I use the above method (sending a 200 response), it locks up for several seconds.  So, if I try to send two different GETS one second apart, the first one arrives, then it hangs for several seconds, then the second one arrives and gets processed.  Is there some additional HTTP responses I could try?  Thanks

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out.  I used self.send_response_only(200).  Thanks for your guidance.